# Can I recover one of my wallets without having my private key or seed phrase?

Tags: seed, private-key, recovery-phrase

I somehow deleted one of my wallets created in phantom without saving the seed phrase or private key. Is there any chance to recover this wallet? And if so how?

Answer (score 2):

If you've lost both the seed phrase and/or private key(s) then I'm afraid its gone for good.